# Merge audio with video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge

I have two videos of different lengths

- Video one: 12 minutes
- Video two: 6 minutes

I want to take audio of video one and the image of video two nd put them together.

Output video length = 6 minutes.

How can I do this with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 12m.mp4 -i 6m.mp4 -c copy -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest new.mp4
```

Comment: thanks for your help
I want to speed up audio and video
What should I do? with command
sorry my eng not good.

Comment: You wish to speed up video from 2nd video and also audio from 1st video? How much?